# Can I show the result of the formula in a pop-up window in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel

Here, I have column D2 in which I used a formula (as shown in picture below) which basically tells me at which rows the duplicates are. For example, texta is repeated in rows 2,5, and 6.

Now, what I'm looking for is a method for me to not show the D2 column but instead when I select texta (B2) it gives me a pop-up window or an output message/comment stating at which rows the duplicates are (i.e 2,5, and 6).

[spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnz6n.png)

Comment: You should use function to create popup windows, this article may help you.
https://www.westernsydney.edu.au/tld/home/how_to/how-to_resources/excel_resources/create_a_pop-up
Then inside the text, you should put your formula result.

Comment: Do you mean the formula and not the formula result? Because I have huge set of data that is needed to be formulated. I'm not sure if I could put the formula itself in the MsgBox? @AndreaTaroni86

Comment: what have you tried since now? Can you show?

Comment: @AndreaTaroni86 
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjR0c.png

Comment: I would use a 'DOUBLE CLICK' event for this and make sure to limit the event to the column of interest. i.e. make sure the code only runs when you double click on the column with the values you want to check duplicates for

Comment: @urdearboy thank you so much for your help! 'DOUBLE CLICK' is a very smart idea and easy to follow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Worksheet `BeforeDoubleClick` to do this. Make sure to update the `Intersect` so the code does not run on all columns.

I just used a simple loop to build the string showing where duplicate rows appear (always excluding the current cell). There are more efficient ways to do this but I'm a bit rusty with VBA so going with simple solution.

Tested and working as expected against a smaller data set

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim Str As String

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lr
        If Range("A" & i).Value = Target.Value And Range("A" & i).Address <> Target.Address Then
            Str = i & ", " & Str
        End If
    Next i
    
    If Len(Str) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Duplicates In Rows: " & Mid(Str, 1, Len(Str) - 2)
    Else
       'Edit to taste
        MsgBox "No Duplicate Rows Found"
    End If
    
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for and very easy to follow.
Great Explanation too! @urdearboy